Сравнить значения из инпутов с массивом значений
Необходимо проверить что текст в каждом инпуте сопадает со своим значнием в массиве


 let inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
      let button = document.querySelector("#btn");

      let texts = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];

      button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        for (let input of inputs) {
          for (let text of texts) {
            if (input.value === text) {
              input.classList.add("right")
            } else {
              input.classList.add("wrong");
              
            }
          }
        }
      });
   <input />
    <input />
    <input />

    <button id="btn">click</button>



Я и перебирал их по всякому, и break добавлял, и чего только не делал. Вроде бы элементарное сравнение значений, но он мне выдаёт всякую дичь)

Забавно конечно, что не один ответ так и не решил вопрос.
В целом задумака была почти правильная, но пробегаться по texts было не правильным. Так же как и добавление класса, без удаления.
С помощью for (можно и .forEach конечно) мы пробежимся по массиву inputs, потом для инпута воспользуемся classList.toggle, почему-то мало кто знает, что у метода toggle есть второй параметр, который добавит класс (если вторым параметром будет true) или удалит класс (если вторым параметром будет false). Во втором параметре мы будем сравниванить значение инпута, со значеием в texts по тому же индексу, что и у инпута.
Готово.


const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
const button = document.querySelector("#btn");

let texts = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];

button.addEventListener("click", () =>
{
    for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
    {
        inputs[i].classList.toggle("right", inputs[i].value === texts[i]);
        inputs[i].classList.toggle("wrong", inputs[i].value !== texts[i]);
    }
});
.right {
  color: green;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
}

.wrong {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
}
<input />
<input />
<input />

<button id="btn">click</button>




Попробуйте так


let button = document.querySelector("#btn");
let texts = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
  inputs.forEach((input, i) => {
    input.classList.remove(); // очищаем текущие классы.
    if (input.value === texts[i]) {
      input.classList.add("right")
    } else {
      input.classList.add("wrong");
    }
  })
});
.right {
  color: green;
}
.wrong {
  color: red;
}
<input />
<input />
<input />

<button id="btn">click</button>



Однако, по хорошему, вам всё же не мешало бы указать инпутам соответствующий атрибут type="text".

input.classList.remove(); не очистит все классы.

@OliverPatterson вы правы про remove(), уже засыпая набрасывал код и не досмотрел, но моё решение с forEach и оно в любом случае было бы без toggle и без тернарной проверки, продиктовано именно тем, что автор вопроса не может справиться с элементарной задачей, так зачем нагружать его кодом который он вряд ли прочтёт? Для себя я бы эту задачу решил в 4–5 строк, и не пользовался бы явным перебором, а засунул бы это в .map.

Проблема в том, что вы получаете все inputы сразу при загрузке страницы, и по этому у них всегда пустое значение в input.value. Для того, чтобы все работала корректно, вам надо каждый раз при клике получить все inputы и сравнить их значения с массивом.
ИЗМЕНЕНО: Добавляю 2 варианта решения. Первый с проверкой 1 input ко всем text[].
Второй с проверкой 1 input к одному text[] по индексу.
<div id="exp-1">
   <input />
   <input />
   <input />
   <button id="btn1">click</button>
</div>
  
<div id="exp-2">
   <input />
   <input />
   <input />
   <button id="btn2">click</button>
</div>

const btn1 = document.querySelector("#btn1");
const btn2 = document.querySelector("#btn2")
const txt = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3'];
        
        
// 1 input ко всем txt[]        
const validateInputExp1 = () => {
   const inputs = document.querySelector("#exp-1").querySelectorAll("input");
            
   for(const input of inputs){
      const value = input.value;
      const isRight = txt.some(v => v === value);
            
      input.setAttribute('style', `color: ${isRight ? 'green' : 'red'}`);
    }
            
}

// 1 input к txt[] по индексу        
const validateInputExp2 = () => {
    const inputs = document.querySelector("#exp-2").querySelectorAll("input");
            
    inputs.forEach((input, i) => {
        const value = input.value;
        const isRight = value === txt[i];
                
        input.setAttribute('style', `color: ${isRight ? 'green' : 'red'}`)
     })
            
}
        
btn1.addEventListener('click', validateInputExp1);
    
btn2.addEventListener('click', validateInputExp2);


Код конечно — каша, но и вы не правы. Всё нормально с input.value, а вот проверка, как и реализация подкачали. Как, вероятно, и ваша. Если я правильно понимаю вопрос, то переменные 'text1', 'text2', 'text3' должны находится именно на своих местах. Ваш же код отработает даже если одну переменную продублировать во все поля или поменять их местами.

Мне предложили несколько вариантов решений. Всем спасибо. Предлагаю свой вариант решения задачи, которая соответсвует  условию, т.е без переключателей и прочего. Огромное спасибо @OliverPatterson за поданную идею с перебором значений массивов в одном цикле)


 let inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
      let button = document.querySelector("#btn");

      let texts = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];
      button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      inputs[i].classList = "";
          if (inputs[i].value == texts[i]) inputs[i].classList.add("right");
          else {
            inputs[i].classList.add("wrong");
          }
        }
      });
  <input />
    <input />
    <input />

    <button id="btn">click</button>




Ваш вариант все равно будет работать не так, у вас не очищаются старые классы.

@OliverPatterson ну тады добавить перед if    inputs[i].classList = '', т.е очищать лист при каждом нажатии)

А если там будут другие классы? Все равно не лучшее решение)
